# Why comparator in qsort has to be in this way?

Tags: c, void-pointers, qsort

According to the C reference the qsort function provided in the standard library has the form

```
void 
qsort ( void * base, size_t num, size_t size, int ( * compar ) ( const void *, const void * ) );
```

My question is why the compar function has to have arguments in the form `const void *` and what does it mean by `const void *`

Another question is if a function takes an argument of the form `const void *`, can it change the value that is pointed by this pointer?

Example:

```
static int double_a_number(const void * val){
    *(int *)val = *(int *)val * 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Will this really double the variable val?

Thanks for help!

Comment: For the second question, can't you just type it in and find out?

Comment: For the second question: yes, provided with call it with the address of a `int` object.

Comment: @Pointy Well it could work in most cases due to undefined behavior. Ins some cases it's just better to know if it'll work always instead of just "in this case".

Comment: @Pointy yes I did and what's odd is it really doubled it. so I am wondering why this could happen.

Comment: @dorafmon well C/C++ are generally willing to let the programmer directly manipulate memory according to explicit requests.

Comment: @Pointy Programming by experimentation ("finding out") is always a bad idea. Especially with C, where many properties are implementation defined, unspecified or undefined. Look ma, printf prints "(null)" when I pass it a null pointer! That's a guarantee for a surprise on the next implementation.

Comment: This question is two questions. As those two question do not necessarily rely one on another, you might better have posted two questions.

Comment: @alk Thanks for letting now, I am a newbie in stackoverflow, I am truly sorry for this.

Answer (score 3):

> why the compar function has to have arguments in the form `const void *`

Because that's the most general type available in C.  Remember that `qsort` can be used to sort arrays of **any** type.

> Another question is if a function takes an argument of the form `const void *`, can it change the value that is pointed by this pointer?

Not without casting away the `const`.  And this is usually a bad idea (it would certainly be unexpected, and it may also lead to undefined behaviour or crashes).  And it certainly makes no sense in a comparator function!

Comment: Is it not also a gentle reminder that a comparator should not mutate the objects which are being compared?

Comment: But actually I tried out the second one and the odd thing is it really changed the value pointed by val. Why this happened?

Comment: @dorafmon: Casting away the `const` and modifying the underlying object is valid if the underlying object isn't really `const`.  But again, it's unexpected (i.e. surprising to users of your function)!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks, I think I got the idea.

Comment: And it's entirely possible that if something is passed as `const` to a function, the compiler relies on you not lying about this, and thus will not re-load the value after the function call -> unexpected effects in the qsort function itself. Why any sane person would write a compare function that alters the value is beyond me...

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I don't think the compiler can do that.  Firstly, it **is** well-defined to cast away the constness and modify an object if it isn't originally `const` (regardless of whether it ends up pointed to via a `const *` at some point).  Secondly, there's also the issue of aliasing.

Comment: I thought I read a comment recently saying that compilers can cache things if they are const, but maybe that was a duff comment. Either way, if you cast the const away, why did you have const in the first place?  [Yes, I know, it can be an interface which you can't change].

Comment: @MatsPetersson: yeah, so far as I understand, `const` hardly helps at all with compiler optimizations, except in an extremely limited set of circumstances.